# Find a line that is perpendicular from x=10 and one point, (4,5)

Tags: linear-algebra, graphing-functions

The title is quite self-explainary ;)

I know that the answer is $y=5$, but I am not sure how does one person come to that conclusions showing all the steps. Can you please help me here?

Comment: Also, I am quite new here. If you think this questions is not good, please say so before downvoting. I am new, and I still haven't figured out why my questions are getting downvoted, and I am scared I will never be able to ask a question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in many ways.

**1)** It is obvious for some.

---

**2)** You can visualize this on your head, or even plot this graph and see clearly.

---

**3) This is the only method that I could think at this time of which you could present if you were asked to prove it.**

$x= 10$ is a vertical line, A perpendicular line to this must be parallel to the x axis. Hence it must have a gradient 0. So it is in the form $y= (0)x+ c=c$

We know two points on this line we are finding which are :

$(4,5)$ and $(10,b)$

> Where b is an unknown

So let's apply the formula for the gradient :

$$\frac{5-b}{4-10}=0$$

$$b=5$$

Now we know the line is in the form $$y=c$$ and since $y=5$ (of any of the two points) we can conclude that the line is $$y=5$$

Comment: This. THIS. THANK YOU :D

Comment: @AhkamNihardeen , You are very welcome :)

Comment: I am still stuck on the last section of the answer. Could you help?

Comment: @AhkamNihardeen sure, which part ? Can you be more specific as to where your stuck in :)

Comment: How did you go from b=5 to y=c and 5? Please help @Tharindu ;)

Comment: @AhkamNihardeen, I concluded that our equation for the line we are searching for is in the form $y=c$ , after that we found that b=5 so our two points on the line are (4,5) and (10,5) From these two points you can see that $y=5$ in each point, so since we said $y = c$ and now we know $y=5$ We can say that $c=5$ , so the equation is $y=5$

Comment: Tada!! Thank you again. I wish I could upvote you, but sadly I cannot (Not enough rep) :(

Comment: Thank you for the rep too! I will try to get more, then I will upvote your question!

Comment: @AhkamNihardeen , No problem :) Glad I was able to help :) And one day, if you gain reputation ;) U can always come back and Upvote if you wish to :)

Comment: CHALLENGE COMPLETED

Comment: @AhkamNihardeen , ;)

Comment: I made my version on the page if you would like to see

Comment: @AhkamNihardeen , I checked it out and (Upvoted!). Brilliantly done :) Im so happy that I was able to help you :)

Comment: Thanks so much @Tharindu :D

Comment: @AhkamNihardeen , Your Welcome :) Wish you All the best :)

Answer (score 1):

I had to do my own version, using @Tharindu's knowledge for my assignment. Here it is if anyone wants a more detailed version. The coordinates are different, since I had a different question:

We need to find an equation that will create a line that is perpendicular to the equation $x=3.58$, given that one point on the line B. As shown in steps beforehand, the point $B$ is equal to $(14.99,8.28)$

Any equation in the form $x=c$ will always make a vertical line. A perpendicular line is a line that intersects on a right angle. Therefore, knowing that $x=3.58$ will always be a vertical line, the perpendicular line will a horizontal line. A horizontal line always has a $m$ value of 0.

Therefore, using the base equation for a linear equation: 
$$y=mx+c$$
Sub in the known values :
$$y=(0)x+c$$
Simplify 
$$y=c$$

That is the equation of our horizontal line as of now. Now, we know one point on this horizontal line, $B$, and we know the $m$ value of the equation is 0.

With this information, we can find the equation of the line using the point-slope formula: 
$$y−y_1=m(x−x_1)$$

Where $y_1$ and $x_1$ can be any point on the line. In this case, we will use the $B$ coordinate.
Co-ordinate of B: $(14.99,8.28)$
Let x=14.99 be $x_1$
Let y=8.28 be $y_1$ 
$(14.99,8.28)$=$(x_1,y_1)$

Point-Slope Formula: 
$$y−y1=m(x−x1)$$

Sub in known values: 
$$y−y1=m(x−x1)$$
$$y−8.28=m(x−14.99)$$
$$y−8.28=0$$
$$y=8.28$$
Therefore, the equation that is perpendicular to the directrix, given that one point on that line has the coordinate (14.99,8.28), is y=8.28